# ElasticSearch mapping "not working" v1.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been struggling over what must be a simple syntax issue, trying to make a basic ES mapping work. This is version 1.1.1

I have a gist to be able to create everything from scratch:

https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/1fc5e296e26e7a5edae0

The mapping query is:

```
PUT /movies/movie/_mapping
{
   "movie": {
      "properties": {
         "director": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                "director": {"type": "string"},
                "original": {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I ran:

```
curl localhost:9200/movies/movie/_mapping?pretty=true
```

to confirm the mapping is actually there

the query:

```
POST /movies/movie/_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "director.original": "Francis Ford Coppola" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

does not get any hits. {"director": "francis"} works as expected.

Greatly appreciate another set of eyes that can tell me what's wrong with this!

Comment: I tried your data set and queries. It is working perfectly fine. It did return 2 results. The difference is i am using elasticsearch version 1.5. But i think version does not matter much

Comment: thank you for your help! I had a feeling it is something local to my setup - nothing else made sense

Comment: Log your query and check it for any unusual stuff. You can do it by setting the slow.log parameter in your config to 0s so that all queries are logged as slow.

Comment: Can you describe your procedure step-by-step please? (inserting docs,mapping definition,etc.) It seems to me that I have figured out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: that's all on the gist, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current mapping which match yours documents is :

```
{
    "movie" : {
        "properties" : {
            "director" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "genres" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "title" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "year" : {
                "type" : "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To match yours mapping and query, documents should be looking like :

```
{
    "director": {
        "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
        "original": "xxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was nothing more than the need to re-index the data after adding the mapping.

Here's an excellent walkthrough for others having this trouble:

https://www.found.no/foundation/mapping-workflow/